# How to remove the top and bottom space on textview of Android

Tags: android, textview, padding, android-custom-view

When I include the below `XML` to *layout* file, I can see the below image. If you see it, you could realize that the `TextView` has top and bottom space.

```
<TextView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="E1"
android:background="#ff00ff00"/>
```

[image]

I wish to remove the space. How to remove it? What is it called?
If anyone has clue.. please let me know. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android: TextView: Remove spacing and padding on top and bottom](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4768738/android-textview-remove-spacing-and-padding-on-top-and-bottom)

Answer (score 99):

Try `android:includeFontPadding="false"` to see if it helps. In my experience that will help a little bit, but there's no way of reducing the TextView dimensions to the exact pixel-perfect text size.

The only alternative, which may or may not give better results, is to cheat a bit and hard-wire the dimensions to match the text size, e.g. `"24sp"` instead of `"wrap_content"` for the height.

Comment: +1 for the second! Just note that I also had to include the includeFontPadding="false", or the text will be cropped a bit.

Comment: this is work for me. but how to remove top and bottom space above and below ascent and descent of text?

Comment: The second clipped my content.

Answer (score 33):

I had the same problem. Attribute `android:includeFontPadding="false"` does not work for me. I've solved this problem in this way:

```
public class TextViewWithoutPaddings extends TextView {

    private final Paint mPaint = new Paint();

    private final Rect mBounds = new Rect();

    public TextViewWithoutPaddings(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public TextViewWithoutPaddings(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public TextViewWithoutPaddings(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(@NonNull Canvas canvas) {
        final String text = calculateTextParams();

        final int left = mBounds.left;
        final int bottom = mBounds.bottom;
        mBounds.offset(-mBounds.left, -mBounds.top);
        mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mPaint.setColor(getCurrentTextColor());
        canvas.drawText(text, -left, mBounds.bottom - bottom, mPaint);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        calculateTextParams();
        setMeasuredDimension(mBounds.width() + 1, -mBounds.top + 1);
    }

    private String calculateTextParams() {
        final String text = getText().toString();
        final int textLength = text.length();
        mPaint.setTextSize(getTextSize());
        mPaint.getTextBounds(text, 0, textLength, mBounds);
        if (textLength == 0) {
            mBounds.right = mBounds.left;
        }
        return text;
    }
}
```

Comment: great solution! tried with different text size and worked like charm :)

Comment: update: in above code, when I use q, g, y, p in lower case they got cut from bottom. So for that change `setMeasuredDimension(mBounds.width() + 1, -mBounds.top + 1);` to `setMeasuredDimension(mBounds.width() + 1, -mBounds.top + mBounds.bottom);`

Comment: looks like performance-wise it's not great idea to call calculateTextParams in onDraw().

Comment: Works. But if you specify android:fontFamily, then change mPaint to getPaint(), otherwise fontFamily is not applied.

Comment: Didn't work for me. It trimmed the padding, but the font was centered to it cut out most of the font as well. Was using a large font (56sp) if that makes a difference.

Comment: It works with a single line but, when I add multiple lines using "\n" it is showing in just a single line.

Answer (score 24):

`android:includeFontPadding="false"` is pretty good but it does not get it precisely. sometimes you want border line accuracy so you can figure it out yourself by applying negative margins:

try setting your bottom and top margins to a negative value.

something like this:

```
android:layout_marginTop="-5dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="-5dp"
```

adjust the values accordingly.

Comment: This did exactly what I needed it to do. This should be the accepted answer. Works on a device running > API 21

Comment: I'm still trying to rationalize the count of upvotes for the answer :))

Comment: this works fine, but is it a scalable solution?

Comment: If my memory serves correctly on the latest constraint layout negative margins now work someone inform me if I'm wrong

Answer (score 5):

This is the code that saved our day. It was adapted using mono C# code from [maksimko](https://github.com/maksimko):

```
public class TopAlignedTextView extends TextView {

    public TopAlignedTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    /*This is where the magic happens*/
    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){

        float offset = getTextSize() - getLineHeight();
        canvas.translate(0, offset);
        super.onDraw(canvas);
    }
}
```

Still had to play around with `textView.setIncludeFontPadding(false)` because we were aligning `TextViews` with different font sizes.

Comment: care to show the stacktrace, instead of down-voting a answer that was useful to a number of users?

Answer (score 4):

I faced the same problem.
Here's a good answer: [How to align the text to top of TextView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1747196/how-to-align-the-text-to-top-of-textview/6573535#6573535)

But code is little unfinished and don't support all font sizes. Change the line

```
int additionalPadding = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 5, getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```

to

```
int additionalPadding = getTextSize() - getLineHeight();
```

Complete C# code (mono) removes top offset:

```
public class TextControl : TextView {
    public TextControl (Context context) : base (context)
    {
        SetIncludeFontPadding (false);
        Gravity = GravityFlags.Top;
    }

    protected override void OnDraw (Android.Graphics.Canvas canvas)
    {
        if (base.Layout == null)
            return;

        Paint.Color = new Android.Graphics.Color (CurrentTextColor);
        Paint.DrawableState = GetDrawableState ();

        canvas.Save ();

        var offset = TextSize - LineHeight;
        canvas.Translate (0, offset);

        base.Layout.Draw (canvas);

        canvas.Restore ();
    }
}
```

Comment: The example referenced inverts the translation amount at the last moment, this code does not. Solution is correct otherwise.

Comment: I have tried a lot of hacks, including the example referenced that defined the arbitrary `TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 5`. Finally, this is the only one that works in order to align 2 TextViews of different  textSizes, without any magic number whatsoever. I would give you +10 if I could :)

Answer (score 3):

Just wanted to add to [**DynamicMind**'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6593885/how-to-remove-the-top-and-bottom-space-on-textview-of-android/6594139#6594139) that the reason why you see spacing around your TextViews is **padding in 9-patch backgrounds** they use by default.

9-patch technology allows you to specify a *content area* which is, effectively, padding. That padding is used unless you set the view's padding explicitly. E.g., when you programmatically set a 9-patch background to a view which had paddings set, they are overridden. And vise-versa, if you set paddings they override what was set by 9-patch background.

Unfortunately, in the XML layout it's not possible to determine the order of these operations. I think just removing the background from your TextViews would help:

```
android:background="@null"
```

Comment: This explains why i had padding i didn't set in my xml. Had to set padding=5dp to override the default padding form 9 patch background.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
public class TopAlignedTextView extends TextView {

    public TopAlignedTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public TopAlignedTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs);
        setIncludeFontPadding(false); //remove the font padding
        setGravity(getGravity() | Gravity.TOP);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        TextPaint textPaint = getPaint();
        textPaint.setColor(getCurrentTextColor());
        textPaint.drawableState = getDrawableState();
        canvas.save();

        //remove extra font padding
        int yOffset = getHeight() - getBaseline();
        canvas.translate(0, - yOffset / 2);

        if (getLayout() != null) {
            getLayout().draw(canvas);
        }
        canvas.restore();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Modified [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32836547/7414207) answer a little bit to use kotlin class and extend `AppCompatTextView`, trimming vertical padding.

It allows setting `android:fontFamily`. Method `calculateTextParams()` moved from `onDraw()` for performance. Not tested for multiple lines of text:

```
import android.content.Context
import android.graphics.Canvas
import android.graphics.Rect
import android.util.AttributeSet
import androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView

class NoPaddingTextView : AppCompatTextView
{
  private val boundsRect = Rect()
  private val textParams = calculateTextParams()

  constructor(context : Context?)
  : super(context)

  constructor(context : Context?, attrs : AttributeSet?)
  : super(context, attrs)

  constructor(context : Context?, attrs : AttributeSet?, defStyleAttr : Int)
  : super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr)

  override fun onDraw(canvas : Canvas)
  {
    with(boundsRect) {
      paint.isAntiAlias = true
      paint.color = currentTextColor
      canvas.drawText(textParams,
                      -left.toFloat(),
                      (-top - bottom).toFloat(),
                      paint)
    }
  }

  override fun onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec : Int, heightMeasureSpec : Int)
  {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec)
    calculateTextParams()
    setMeasuredDimension(boundsRect.width() + 1, -boundsRect.top + 1)
  }

  private fun calculateTextParams() : String
  {
    return text.toString()
    .also {text ->
      text.length.let {textLength ->
        paint.textSize = textSize
        paint.getTextBounds(text, 0, textLength, boundsRect)
        if(textLength == 0) boundsRect.right = boundsRect.left
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you defined a layout margin? 
For example:

```
android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
```

Otherwise, if your text view is wrapped inside a LinearLayout or other container, then that cold have either padding or a margin too.

Answer (score 0):

```
android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background"
```

use it according to you change it that you want editbox_background.
because android provide some build in background like above code choose according to your requirement.
May be it is help full to you.

Answer (score 0):

Inside a LinearLayout the default padding might be an issue. Try setting it to 0dp. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32836547/703225) of TopAlignedTextView code:[TopAlignedTextView@GitHub](https://github.com/captain-miao/TopAlignedTextView)

use it by layout:

```
<com.github.captain_miao.view.TopAlignedTextView
    android:id="@+id/text_a"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:text="@string/text_demo_a"
/>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

My way for fixing this is pretty hacky, but I managed to get the text to sit where I wanted by setting the height of the text view as static and fiddling with it until it just barely fit the text. In my case, the font style I was using had a height of 64sp so I set the height of my textview to 50sp and it worked okay. I also had to set foreground_gravity to bottom.

Answer (score -1):

```
android:includeFontPadding="false"
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.