# How to remove TextView top margin?

Tags: android, textview, margin

I do have a problem with `TextView`. I don't want to have any margin/padding above it.

```
<TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:id="@+id/ptp_hour"
          android:textColor="@color/black"
          android:textSize="100dp"
          android:height="100dp"
          android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
          android:paddingTop="0dp"
          android:includeFontPadding="false"
          android:maxLines="1"
          android:text="10"/>
```

My `TextView` looks like this and despite the `textSize` and `height` are set to the same value, there is a space above font. It bothers me because I want to put another view relatively to the top of the font. Is this spacing included into font itself?

[image: TextView in RelativeLayout]

And another question: If I found out that margin 20dp from top and 7dp from bottom works perfectly on my device, can I rely that it will behave in a similar way on other screens?
(these margins are for buttons)

Comment: Can you post an image of what you're seeing?

Comment: yes please post an image

Comment: It seems possible the font will have top spacing. Try keeping the height as 100dp but increasing the textSize (102dp or 105dp etc).

Comment: @MisterSquonk If I increase `textSize` font is cut from down.

Comment: @MichalChudy: See my answer. i have solved your issue.

Comment: Have you seen the post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6593885/how-to-remove-the-top-and-bottom-space-on-textview-of-android and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4768738/android-textview-remove-spacing-and-padding-on-top-and-bottom

Comment: do you want text "10" and "45" to touch above and below edge and let the buttons be as they are??

Answer (score 47, accepted):

using `android:includeFontPadding="false"` helped me a lot in a similar situation.

Answer (score 10):

I had the same issue where setting `android:includeFontPadding=false` did not help. The best solution I could find in reasonable time was to override the TextView's `onDraw` method and to adjust the canvas for the difference between the font metrics' top and ascent values:

```
FontMetricsInt fontMetricsInt;
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    if (adjustTopForAscent){
        if (fontMetricsInt == null){
            fontMetricsInt = new FontMetricsInt();
            getPaint().getFontMetricsInt(fontMetricsInt);
        }
        canvas.translate(0, fontMetricsInt.top - fontMetricsInt.ascent);
    }
    super.onDraw(canvas);
}
```

Comment: This almost works, in a TextView with a small font it aligns perfectly. On a 74sp font, not that much. But +1 for this fine solution.

Answer (score 2):

What you need to do is to put the other view relative to the top of the font, and give it a negative `android:layout_marginBottom` in dip, such that it matches the top of the font. If the font has a margin, I don't think there is a better way of doing it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes this space included by default. You are not able to remove that space as per my search area. So you need to have to implement some logic to have such view.

See below Image:

[image]

Its not a good idea but you can do like below code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:background="#ffffff">
    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"           
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"           
        android:id="@+id/ptp_hour"           
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"           
        android:textSize="100sp"
        android:lineSpacingMultiplier="0.8"
        android:scrollY="-100dp"
        android:scrollX="100dp"
        android:text="10"/>
    <TextView 
        android:text="10"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#00FFFFFF"
        android:shadowColor="#000000"
        android:shadowDy="-50"
        android:shadowRadius="1"
        android:textSize="100dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Here, first "10" is of your properties and second one is as i have set for you.

Enjoy.  :))

Comment: You can achieve the same with having android:lineSpacingExtra set to a negative value. But both of them have the problem that the TextView will clip characters out of bounds like g, q, p.

Comment: Funny hack, I think. But not useful if I want remove bottom extra space too.

Comment: please follow @Maurycy's answer. it is the right things needed to do for same.