# Why does the TextView has padding even though I've set it to 0

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

As you can see in the following definition I set the top padding of a TextView to zero:

```
 <TextView 
   android:id = "@+id/headline"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
   android:paddingTop="0dip"
   android:textColor="@color/light_grey"
   android:layout_toRightOf="@id/logoImage"
   android:layout_marginLeft = "8dp"
   android:textSize="13sp"
   android:textStyle="bold"
   android:background="@color/magenta"
   android:text="Platzhalter"/>
```

But the TextView still has padding:

[image]

Does anybody have an idea how to solve this issue?

edit:
The comments are right, the problem isn't the padding but the font. Setting includeFontPadding to false doesn't produce a perfect result, but it helps a lot and the result is good enough for now. 
For other people having the same problem: Thorstenvv's answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8465969/how-to-remove-textview-top-margin) sounds promising.

Comment: show the parent container

Comment: I don't think that's padding. That might just be due to the font metrics. That would be the difference between the line height and the cap height.

Comment: Have you played around with the `includeFontPadding` flag (or its [equivalent setter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setIncludeFontPadding%28boolean%29))? The results will vary based on the font used, but it may be worth a shot.