# Android unwanted padding on top and bottom with TextView

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

I am trying to put two text view within the circular progress bar as shown in the picture below. These two text should be aligned with center of the circular progress bar.
[image]

But the unwanted padding in text view which prevents me to align the text into the center of the circular progress bar. This is what i get.

[image]
[image]

here is my layout file:

```
 <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/onboarding_activity_progress_layout"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

            <com.locationlabs.finder.android.core.ui.CircularProgressBar
                  android:id="@+id/onboarding_activity_progress_bar"
                  android:layout_gravity="center"
                  android:padding="10dp"
                  android:layout_width="120dp"
                  android:layout_height="120dp"
                  app:progressColor="@color/progress_bar_color"
                  app:backgroundColor="@color/progress_bar_background_color"
                  app:progressBarWidth="10dp"
                  tools:progress="60"/>
            <LinearLayout
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:orientation="vertical"
                  android:includeFontPadding="false"
                  android:layout_gravity="center">

                <TextView
                      android:id="@+id/number_of_remaining_steps"
                      style="@style/OnboardingNumberOfRemainingStepText"
                      tools:text="2"/>

                <TextView
                      android:id="@+id/remaining_number_of_steps"
                      style="@style/OnboardingRemainingStepText"
                      tools:text="steps left"/>

            </LinearLayout>
        </FrameLayout>
```

Here is the styling:

```
<style name="OnboardingNumberOfRemainingStepText">
        <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_gravity">center_horizontal</item>
        <item name="android:fontFamily">sans-serif</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">40sp</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/dark_grey</item>
        <item name="android:includeFontPadding">false</item>
    </style>

  <style name="OnboardingRemainingStepText">
        <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_gravity">center_horizontal</item>
        <item name="android:fontFamily">sans-serif-light</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/dark_grey</item>
        <item name="android:textStyle">normal</item>
    </style>
```

I was told `android:includeFontPadding` can help reduce the padding but it doesn't help that much. I also tried with the single textView with Spannable but I get almost the similar result. I tried with negative margin but that didn't work and it is also not reliable.

Comment: I think it's the TextSize, try setting it to something lower.

Comment: @MikeM I have already tried with padding `0dp` but it didn't help.
@VeereshCharantimath I don't want to lower the `textSize`.

Comment: Did you try setting the width of the linear layout that holds the text views to 120dp?

Comment: @Francesc it doesn't help. It moves the text little bit up and it overlaps with the circular progress bar and the padding between two textview are still the same.

Comment: Did you try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23063015/3792350)? Wrap a TextView and override the onDraw to remove top and bottom space.

Comment: @sakiM I tried that already it removes the padding from the bottom but the top padding is still there. This prevents both the textView to align completely with the center of the circular progress bar.

Comment: I tried [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30763169/1024482) solution and it works.

Comment: @Rakesh I found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32836547/3792350) looks more reasonable. I tried this solution and it can crop all the padding perfectly.

Comment: @sakiM This is the exactly the same link which I have posted above. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

When you transfer styling attributes of a TextView to XML, TextView might render in an unexpected way. This is because the default styling for TextView is applied in a layout file which is overridden when you use *style* attribute in it.

You can try using *parent="android:TextAppearance"* in the style defined for a TextView to ensure you inherit the pre-defined styles for the TextView.

Example:

Let me know if it worked for you!