# Allign text inside TextView to it's border completely

Tags: android, android-layout

Even when `gravity` is set to `top` the text has some padding between it and `view`'s border. I need to text to completely touch the border.

Bellow you can see the gap I'm trying to get rid of.

[image: Text not touching view's border]

And here is the layout used:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/someView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Here is some text"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:gravity="top" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: what is the built in padding??? I dont know about that. i think we can force the text to be in a direction by using android:gravity attribute of the TextView

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? This is a pretty vague statement, are you trying to get it to align to the left or right or something? Based on your question I would say use margin or padding, but apparently that isn't what you need...

Comment: Thank you for your input I edited the question so it's more clear (I hope). @zgc7009

Comment: android:includeFontPadding="false" in your TextView. Sorry I just misunderstood your question at first, the image did it for me :P

Comment: @zgc7009, tried it already and unfortunately it will still leave a gap

Comment: reference the answer:[How to remove the top and bottom space on textview of Android](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40072552/703225)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to create 9.patch line and set it to your TextView: `android:drawableTop="@drawable/your_line"`. 
Then set `android:drawablePadding="-10dp"`

This trick must work perfectly.

Comment: Thanks your solution is the **only** one that works. No need to use 9.patch though, a simple `color` will do fine as well. I'll edit your answer to show the layout.

Answer (score 1):

Try this on TextView in your xml file :

```
android:includeFontPadding="false"
```

--

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/someView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Here is some text"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:includeFontPadding="false"
        android:gravity="top" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: This single line worked. I can't believe I'm the first upvote on this answer since it was created :)

Answer (score 0):

<strike>In xml try,
    android:paddingTop="-5dp"</strike>

Negative paddings always seem to work for me.

Set the height manually instead of wrapping the content.

The linear layout is the item with the padding. You need to modify that element as well to remove the space.

Comment: Well it doesn't in this case

Comment: Edited for a different solution

Comment: This will cut the text from the bottom but will not move it closer to the border.