# Android TextView chopping off text

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

Having fiddled with this for longer than I care to admit, how does text alignment work within a TextView?

[image]

Obviously I'm trying to get the 'N' to centre itself vertically in the TextView.

```
    <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/titleN"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:height="114dp"
    android:textSize="120dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"/>
```

When I remove height it looks like:

[image]

Comment: Please post the code which shows what you have done. We cannot tell you how to fix this without knowing what you did in the first place.

Comment: Is it because the `height` is less than the `textSize`? You don't need this value at all.

Comment: I've tried many different values trying to get it to line up with the TextViews next to it. I'll use whatever values work...

Comment: Remove android:height="114dp" attribute from your textview.
Or Update android:height="114dp" to android:height="120dp".

Comment: Different fonts have differently alignment. What do you want to achieve? Maybe try setting the text in right as layout_alignBottom

Comment: It doesn't help that the simulator dimensions are off compared to the Moto G that I test on. I'm trying to get the 'N' bottom to align with the bottom sentence next to it.

Comment: What happens if you remove the `layout_gravity` and `gravity` attributes?

Comment: If you are setting the text size explicitly you can use `wrap_content` for the height of the text view. However, note that text size should be given in sp, not dp.

Comment: wrap_content isn't a valid value for height? @Code-Apprentice nothing

Comment: @zgc7009 The OP has already set `layout_height` to `wrap_content`. `height` is different...and I'm not sure what the point is of having two attributes seemingly for the same thing..

Comment: My fault, looked at it wrong :P Yea I agree with @Code-Apprentice no need to set a height attribute in this case. Having the wrap_content attribute should handle the height for you. Not that it should have an effect, but try using sp instead of dp for the text size.

Comment: Try align_bottom textView3 to textView

Comment: I found this, see if it helps.
http://stackoverflow.com/a/6594320/2346980

Comment: @Keshav the 'blue box' alignment appears correct, it's the position of the text within that is the issue, though from your link setting android:layout_marginTop to a negative figure appears to work for me

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `TextView's height(114dp)` is smaller than the size of the `text (120dp)` itself, remove the height attribute from the `TextView`, you don't need this line

```
android:height="114dp" // you need to remove this attribute from the TextView
```

What you need is `android:gravity="center_vertical"`

when the gravity of the `textview` is set for `center_vertical` text will remain in the center irrespective of the `textView`'s height

Example:-

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:text="N"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
```

> Output

[image]

Comment: @user1561108, did you remove this line android:height="114dp"

Comment: Yes no effect either.

Comment: @user1561108, can you post updated TextView, i would like to see what changes you made, I will try to fix it

Answer (score 0):

as per @Keshav's link to https://stackoverflow.com/a/6594320/2346980, setting `android:layout_marginTop` to a negative value corrected the text position inside TextView.

Answer (score 0):

Try using maring attributes, like margin-top or margin-bottom. If that doesnt work try using padding, like padding-top or padding-bottom