# In a TextView, what's the height of blank between the content text and the border of the TextView?

Tags: android, textview

There will be a blank between the content text and the border of the `TextView`, even if the `padding` is 0. And if the height of the `TextView` and the content text is set to a same value, the text will not be completely displayed.

So, what's the height of blank between the content text and the border of the TextView?

Answer (score 1):

The extra spacing is built into the font. It's there to accomodate special characters that are very tall.

Similar question: [How to remove the top and bottom space on textview of Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6593885/how-to-remove-the-top-and-bottom-space-on-textview-of-android)

Adding `android:includeFontPadding="false"` may help a little, but I've found it doesn't do much.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! The `android:includeFontPadding="false"` actually reduces the height of the space. But, there is still some space between the text and the border. I don't care whether the space exists or not, but is there a way to abtain the size of this space? And then I can place the text exactly where the designer want..

Comment: I know the feeling. If the text is static, setting a negative margin may do the trick. Otherwise, see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6573535/2113225