# Android add textview at position 0,0 is not working

Tags: android, textview, position

I try to add a textview to a relative layout at position 0,0 !

Following code is used:

```
TextView text = new TextView(getActivity());
    text.setTextColor(Color.RED);
    text.setIncludeFontPadding(false);
    text.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
    text.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, 32 * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);
    text.setText("TEST TEXT");
    text.setSingleLine(false);
    text.setX(0);
    text.setY(0);
    text.setTypeface(fct.getFont().getTypeFace(getActivity())); container.addView(text);
```

container is a relative layout defined here:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+frontcard/container"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    />
```

I use a custom font with the textview...

The problem is that the text view is not displayed correctly.
There is a padding to the top ... left is set correct.

Image for the output:

[Image as Textview](https://www.dropbox.com/s/q8xiyzor6psdpof/2015-05-26%2016.19.30.png?dl=0)

If i draw it on a canvas everything works fine like this image shows:

[Image as Bitmap](https://www.dropbox.com/s/cxazzxf46eysudi/2015-05-26%2016.19.44.png?dl=0)

Do i have a problem with the custom font in a textview ?

Anyone has any ideas ?

Comment: im not sure but the TextView has a natural margin in top and bottom, try text.setGravity(Gravity.TOP);

Comment: Great idea... unfortunately it is not working :/
I guess there is something with the padding of the custom font

Answer (score 0):

try adding

```
text.setIncludeFontPadding(false);
```

Comment: or set negative top padding

Comment: 3rd line i use exactly this... 

User can switch fonts so a static negative padding is not so solution

Comment: yep even without custom font its not working... there is a padding to the top and i dont know why

Comment: here is an answer for similar problem: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6573535/4937232

Comment: This is not a good solution... it just sets a negativ padding to the textview

Comment: yes, but there is a discussion about textview top and bottom padding, it could help in thinking of a solution.